# Enumerating subkeys with CSettingsStore

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, registry

I have been looking at using [`CSettingsStore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/csettingsstore-class?view=vs-2019) class.

I know how to read a value from the registry. Example:

```cpp
CSettingsStore store(TRUE, TRUE);

if (store.Open(_T("Software\\TruckleSoft\\VisitsRota")))
{
    if (store.Read(_T("AppPath"), m_strPathVisitsRota))
    {
        //yes, but is the path still valid
        if (!PathFileExists(m_strPathVisitsRota))
        {
            // it exists
            m_strPathVisitsRota = _T("");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in the documentation is states:

> The security access depends on the `bReadOnly` parameter. If `bReadonly` is `FALSE`, the security access will be set to `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`. If `bReadyOnly` is `TRUE`, the security access will be set to a combination of `KEY_QUERY_VALUE`, `KEY_NOTIFY` and **`KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS`**.

So it implies you can enumerate sub keys. But I can't find an example explaining about to enumerate a set of key / value pairs using this class.

Comment: I am not familiar with this class, but it doesn't seem to have any enum method. It has `ATL::CRegKey m_reg` but that's protected. You have to derive your own class `class CMySettingsStore : public CSettingsStore`, use `m_reg` to enumerate the keys.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Perhaps I will request it as a feature. Seems a reasonable improvement.

Comment: Does Microsoft respond to MFC update requests? It's probably easier to just write it.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I posted it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/528425/enumerating-subkeys-with-csettingsstore.html

Comment: @BarmakShemirani They have not responded in 2 years. So I think I got to write it. This is the only thing keeping me using another suite of classes now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS` is a flag which request access to enumerate the subkeys, it doesn't actually do it.

`KEY_ALL_ACCESS` is a combination of different flags, including `KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS`. So in both cases enumeration access is requested.

To enumerate values we need `::RegEnumValue` API, this method is not wrapped in `CRegKey`, but it doesn't matter, we can get `HKEY` directly.

Here is example, based on your code and [Microsoft sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/enumerating-registry-subkeys)

```
void CMySettingsStore::EnumKeys(std::vector<CString>& vec)
{
    vec.clear();
    DWORD subkey_total;
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != RegQueryInfoKey(m_reg.m_hKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        &subkey_total, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL))
        return;
    wchar_t buf[1024];
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < subkey_total; i++)
    {
        DWORD len = _countof(buf);
        if (ERROR_SUCCESS == m_reg.EnumKey(i, buf, &len))
            vec.push_back(buf);
    }
}

void CMySettingsStore::EnumValues(std::vector<CString>& vec)
{
    vec.clear();
    DWORD values_total;
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != RegQueryInfoKey(m_reg.m_hKey, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, &values_total, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL))
        return;
    wchar_t buf[1024];
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < values_total; i++)
    {
        DWORD len = _countof(buf);
        if (ERROR_SUCCESS == RegEnumValue(m_reg.m_hKey, i, buf, &len,
            NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)) 
            vec.push_back(buf);
    }
}
```

---

#### Udpate from Question Author

This code does not resolve all the code analysis warnings but it does add error handling and support for obtaining the value **types**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MySettingsStore.h"

CMySettingsStore::CMySettingsStore(BOOL bAdmin, BOOL bReadOnly)
    : CSettingsStore(bAdmin, bReadOnly)
{

}

bool CMySettingsStore::EnumKeys(std::vector<CString>& vec)
{
    vec.clear();

    DWORD subkey_total{}, lResult{};
    if (RegQueryInfoKey(m_reg.m_hKey, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        &subkey_total, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        const DWORD dwError = ::GetLastError();
        AfxMessageBox(GetLastErrorAsString(dwError), MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
        return false;
    }

    wchar_t buf[1024];
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < subkey_total; i++)
    {
        DWORD len = _countof(buf);
        lResult = m_reg.EnumKey(i, buf, &len);
        if(lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS || ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
            vec.push_back(buf);
    }

    if (lResult != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
    {
        const DWORD dwError = ::GetLastError();
        AfxMessageBox(GetLastErrorAsString(dwError), MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}

bool CMySettingsStore::EnumValues(std::map<CString, DWORD>& map)
{
    map.clear();
    DWORD values_total{}, dwType{}, lResult{};
    if (RegQueryInfoKey(m_reg.m_hKey, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, &values_total, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        const DWORD dwError = ::GetLastError();
        AfxMessageBox(GetLastErrorAsString(dwError), MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
        return false;
    }

    wchar_t buf[1024];
    for (DWORD i = 0; i < values_total; i++)
    {
        DWORD len = _countof(buf);

        lResult = RegEnumValue(m_reg.m_hKey, i, buf, &len,
            NULL, &dwType, NULL, NULL);
        if(lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS || lResult == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
            map.emplace(buf, dwType);
    }

    if (lResult != ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
    {
        const DWORD dwError = ::GetLastError();
        AfxMessageBox(GetLastErrorAsString(dwError), MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

CString CMySettingsStore::GetLastErrorAsString(DWORD dwError)
{
    LPVOID  lpMsgBuf{};
    CString strError;

    ::FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        nullptr,
        dwError,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0,
        nullptr);

    strError = static_cast<LPTSTR>(lpMsgBuf);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);

    return strError;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. I get a few analysis warnings (pointer decay etc., and using `nullptr` instead of `NULL`. But I can look at that. I will look at adding error handing since as you say the EnumKey returns a specific value for success, complete or error. And, for the `EnumValues` I had to pass a `std::map<CString, DWORD>` as I needed to know the type of value.

Comment: I added a second version of the code to your answer - was that OK? Thanks.

Comment: The only warning we have (after changoing the `NULL` to `nullptr` is our usage of that buffer and pointer decay.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is a work in progress.

#### Header

```
#pragma once
#include <afxsettingsstore.h>
#include <vector>

class CMySettingsStore :
    public CSettingsStore
{
public:
    CMySettingsStore(BOOL bAdmin, BOOL bReadOnly);
    void EnumKey(std::vector<CString> &vecKeys);
};
```

#### Source

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CMySettingsStore.h"

CMySettingsStore::CMySettingsStore(BOOL bAdmin, BOOL bReadOnly)
    : CSettingsStore(bAdmin, bReadOnly)
{

}

void CMySettingsStore::EnumKey(std::vector<CString>& vecKeys)
{
    DWORD dwIndex = 0;
    long lResult = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    vecKeys.clear();

    while (lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        CString strSubKey;
        DWORD dwLength = _MAX_PATH;
        lResult = m_reg.EnumKey(dwIndex, strSubKey.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH), &dwLength);
        strSubKey.ReleaseBuffer();

        dwIndex++;

        vecKeys.push_back(strSubKey);
    }
}
```

#### Test Code

Code assumes there is a `CListBox` control on your dialog:

```
CMySettingsStore mySettings(FALSE, TRUE);

if (mySettings.Open(_T("Software\\xxxx")))
{
    std::vector<CString> list;
    mySettings.EnumKey(list);
    mySettings.Close();

    for (const auto& strSubKey : list)
    {
        m_lbData.AddString(strSubKey);
    }
}
```

---

The above works and gives me a list of subkeys for the specified key. However, I have not yet worked out how to **enumerate the values** in a given key.

Comment: `lResult = m_reg.EnumKey(...)` could fail, we should break immediately, otherwise we get an extra subkey with value `""`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Good point. I have adopted your answer suggestion and provided tweaked code to your answer.